# Dynamic name to key value in JSON

Tags: json

I have the below JSON code and i want the invoke to contain the name of the substate machine i select from the option. Something like invoke_substatemachinename. If i change the name of the selectoptions i can no longer access the options.

```
{
    "categoryName": "End",
    "subStateMachine": "false",
    "eventName": "Event_1",
    "properties": [],
    "selectedOptionName": "end",
    "selectOptions": [{
        "name": "return",
        "value": "0"
    }, {
        "name": "invoke",
        "value": "1"
    }, {
        "name": "end",
        "value": "-1"
    }],
    "dynamicProperties": {
        "return": [{
            "name": "SubStateMachine",
            "type": "radio",
            "options": [{
                "name": "true",
                "value": "true"
            }, {
                "name": "false",
                "value": "false"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "Event Name",
            "type": "select",
            "options": []
        }, {
            "type": "table",
            "title": "Event Parameters"
        }],
        "invoke": [{
            "name": "SubStateMachine",
            "type": "select",
            "options": []
        }, {
            "name": "Event Name",
            "type": "select",
            "options": []
        }, {
            "type": "table",
            "title": "Event Parameters"
        }]
    }
}
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: JSON isn't programmable by itself. Presumably you're processing this in JavaScript or some other language? I think you're asking how to look up the selectedOptionName in your selectOptions array and then store the value in dynamicPropertes.invoke somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got your point.

```
"invoke": [{
        "name": "SubStateMachine",
        "type": "select",
        "options": []
    }, {
        "name": "Event Name",
        "type": "select",
        "options": []
    }, {
        "type": "table",
        "title": "Event Parameters"
    }]
```

This is not the good structure for your goal. You need to have the name of the machine as a key of your object, not having a list of objects.

You can use:

```
"invoke": {
    "SubStateMachine" : {
        "type": "select",
        "options": []
    }, "Event Name" : {
        "type": "select",
        "options": []
    }, "Empty" : {
        "type": "table",
        "title": "Event Parameters"
    }
}
```

Like this you can access the options of your machine by typing: invoke["substateMachineName"], or invoke["Event Name"]. You can also easily add properties to invoke.

Comment: when i choose invoke  it gives me an option to choose a substate machine. i want to pass the name of the chosen substatemachine to the invoke. so the name of my final invoke should be something like invoke_nameofthechosensubstatemachine.      "invoke": [{
            "name": "SubStateMachine",
            "type": "select",
            "options": []
        }, {
            "name": "Event Name",
            "type": "select",
            "options": []
        }, {
            "type": "table",
            "title": "Event Parameters"
        }]